# Dagger2 Subcomponent module override

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

`ApplicationComponent.java`

```
@Component(modules = SomeModule.class)
@ApplicationScope
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    // stuff
    ActivityComponent activityComponent();
}
```

`ActivityComponent.java`

```
@Subcomponent(modules = AnotherModule.class)
@ActivityScope
public interface ActivityComponent {
    // stuff
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

`SomeModule` can be overriden using something like [this](http://artemzin.com/blog/jfyi-overriding-module-classes-with-dagger2/). But how about `AnotherModule`?

One solution would be to separate the 2 components, but what if I want to reuse some bindings from the parent?

edit:

`MainActivity.java`

```
onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    getApplicationComponent().getActivityComponent().inject(this);
}
```

edit2:

`ActivityRyle.java`

```
init() {
    application.setComponent(DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                    .someModule(new TestSomeModule(application))
                    .build();
}
```

edit3: I'm trying to avoid wiring too much stuff in `Application` (where the main component is created).

Comment: Please always include everything relevant in your question, and don't just link to external samples.

Answer (score 1):

You also just override the module.

Please keep in mind, how you *create* subcomponents:

```
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    ActivityComponent activityComponent(/*needed modules go here*/);
}
```

So unless you have no-args constructors for modules, you have to put them as parameters in the method declaration.

If you want to be able to override modules with a no-arg constructor, you'd have to add them to your method signature:

```
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    ActivityComponent activityComponent(AnotherModule module);
}
```

And in your test you just supply your subclass.

Comment: Post updated with sample code how `ActivityComponent` is used. In the test, how would I pass in a test module? For `ApplicationComponent`, it can be done in an `ActivityTestRule`, and set a component to the current Application. But I can't find a way to do such thing for subcomponent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the module as an input parameter of your subcomponent factory method.

Comment: Where/how would I pass the test module?

Comment: Instead of `ActivityComponent activityComponent();` write  `ActivityComponent activityComponent(AnotherModule anotherModule)`

Comment: Yes, I get that part, but from within your test, how to assign the test module to that component, such that the activity is using it? Add a `setActivityComponent` in the main `Application`?